Using the Go Aurora SDK seems to occasionally connect to read only instance
I'm using GO (in a lambda) to connect to a serverless Aurora DB. I have a read and write instance. When creating the client I do the following:
region := "eu-west-2"
config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithRegion(region))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

auroraClient := rdsdata.NewFromConfig(config)

sqlStatement := `...`

input := &rdsdata.ExecuteStatementInput{
    ResourceArn:     &auroraClusterARN, // This is the cluster ARN not an instance ARN
    SecretArn:       &auroraSecretsStoreARN,
    Database:        &auroraDatabaseName,
    Sql:             &sqlStatement,
    FormatRecordsAs: types.RecordsFormatTypeJson,
}

auroraClient.ExecuteStatement(a.ctx, input)

when I make the above query, I'm !sometimes! getting the error:
DatabaseErrorException: Running in read-only mode; Error code: 1836; SQLState: HY000

I'm assuming the connection is being cached, and the reader / writer instances have been switched. But I don't understand why the go sdk is not handling this? Am i missing some config?
(I have set the aurora db to scale down to 0 capacity after 5min of inactivity, and I tend to see this error after it starts back up. But won't go away once the db has started.)
